# form not saving into user model Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm currently processing a payment thing for an online subscription service and in order to get the users info to send this stuff, I have a payment form.

But, for some reason the payment form is not saving to the users account.  Everything else actually processes and the only error I can trigger is a 'NOT NULL constraint failed: memberships_usermembership.user_id'

Here's what I have in my view -

```
@login_required()
def payments(request):
    user_membership = get_user_membership(request)
    selected_membership = get_selected_membership(request)
    form = SubscriptionForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form_data = {
                'full_name': request.POST['full_name'],
                'email': request.POST['email'],
                'phone_number': request.POST['phone_number'],
                'country': request.POST['country'],
                'postcode': request.POST['postcode'],
                'town_or_city': request.POST['town_or_city'],
                'street_address1': request.POST['street_address1'],
                'street_address2': request.POST['street_address2'],
                'county': request.POST['county'],
            }
        token = request.POST['stripeToken']
        form = SubscriptionForm(form_data)

        if form.is_valid():
            customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(
                user_membership.stripe_customer_id)
            customer.source = token
            customer.save()

            subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
                customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id,
                items=[
                    {"plan": selected_membership.stripe_plan_id},
                ]
            )
            user_membership = get_user_membership(request)
            selected_membership = get_selected_membership(request)
            user_membership.membership = selected_membership
            user_membership.save()
            form.save(commit=True)

            subscription_id = subscription.id
            sub, created = Subscription.objects.get_or_create(
                user_membership=user_membership)
            sub.stripe_subscription_id = subscription_id
            sub.active = True
            sub.save()
            

            try:
                del request.session['selected_membership_type']
            except BaseException:
                pass

            return render(request, 'memberships/update-success.html')
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('membership_list'))

    context = {
        'selected_membership': selected_membership,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'memberships/payment.html', context)
```

When the form.save() is the line above the return(render) line, it will process everything as normal, and the form information just wont save into the DB.
It flashes the NOT NULL error when the form.save() line is where it in in the code above.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a link to the entire error in Django - http://dpaste.com/140VD8M

[& a screenshot of it too!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH8Z7.png)

Here's my models -

```
    class Membership(models.Model):
    membership_type = models.CharField(
        choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,
        default='Free',
        max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=15)
    description = models.TextField(default="DESCRIPTION")
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    stripe_plan_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.membership_type


class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='Country',  default="Ireland")
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    town_or_city = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    street_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    street_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(
        Membership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def post_save_usermembership_create(
        sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    user_membership, created = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(
        user=instance)

    if user_membership.stripe_customer_id is None or user_membership.stripe_customer_id == '':
        new_customer_id = stripe.Customer.create(email=instance.email)
        free_membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')
        user_membership.stripe_customer_id = new_customer_id['id']
        user_membership.membership = free_membership
        user_membership.save()


post_save.connect(post_save_usermembership_create,
                  sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)


class Subscription(models.Model):
    user_membership = models.ForeignKey(
        UserMembership, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_membership.user.username
```

& here's my user membership def -

```
    @login_required()
def get_user_membership(request):
    user_membership_qs = UserMembership.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if user_membership_qs.exists():
        return user_membership_qs.first()
    return None
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are getting

Comment: @MichaelHawkins Just added it there! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of collecting all the form fields individually, you should be able to just pass the `request.POST` to the form like so:

```
    form_data = request.POST
    token = request.POST['stripeToken']
    form = SubscriptionForm(form_data)
```

Other than that, without seeing the exact error message, there isn't much more to tell. If you update your question I will update my answer.

**EDIT:**

Without seeing your model and what `get_user_membership()` returns, it looks like you are missing a User object in a UserMembership class (but I can't tell without seeing more):

```
 user_membership.user = request.user
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Hey! Sorry ,I've just updated it now, I've added a screenshot too!

Comment: The error is coming from a model. Can you post your models? There is a missing User attribute somewhere. Can you post the get_user_membership() function?

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for the help! I've just added them there :)